# How to dynamically change a nested state with a recursive function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, javascript-objects

I am quite new to react an I want to learn how to dynamically update states in deep nested objects.

Let's say I have a deep nested object as:

```
 const initialState = [
      { a: [{ a: [{ a: [{ a: 5 }, { b: 4 }] }, { b: 3 }] }, { b: 2 }] },
      { b: 1 },
    ];
```

I want to render each "b" value in a different button and onClick to increment it's value.
Something like this:
[buttons image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mqbh6.png)

To do that I want to use a recursive function.
With this I can display all items but I don't know how to do the state update of each individual nested state in the button.

My code so far is:

```
function RecursiveComponent({ nestedObject, setNestedObject }) { 

      function handleIncrement() { //this event handler it's not correct for updating the nested states,
       setNestedObject((prevState) => {
          prevState[1].b = prevState[1].b + 1;
          return { ...prevState };
        });
      }

      return (
        <>
          {nestedObject && (
            <div>
              <button onClick={handleIncrement}>{nestedObject[1].b}</button>
              {typeof nestedObject[0].a === "object" && (
                <RecursiveComponent
                  nestedObject={nestedObject[0].a}
                  setNestedObject={setNestedObject}
                />
              )}
            </div>
          )}
        </>
      );
    }
    
    function App() {
      const [nestedObject, setNestedObject] = useState(initialState);
    
      function handleIncrement() {
        setNestedObject((prevState) => {
          prevState[1].b = prevState[1].b + 1;
          return { ...prevState };
        });
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          {nestedObject && (
            <button onClick={handleIncrement}>{nestedObject[1].b}</button>
          )}
          {nestedObject && typeof nestedObject[0].a === "object" && (
            <RecursiveComponent
              nestedObject={nestedObject[0].a}
              setNestedObject={setNestedObject}
            />
          )}
        </>
      );
    }
```

So I have two questions:

**1. How to update each nested state dynamicaly?**

**2. Why when I click on the first event it increases by 1 but after that when clicking again it increases by 2??**